# Python - Instantiating a class without assigning a name to the instance

Tags: python, class, instantiation, identifier

A Python newbie here!

The example below is about the difference between instantiating a class then assigning a name to the instance, and instantiating without assignment.

In the last three lines of the example, the method is first called on the instance (my_city), then it is called without an instance. So:

1. What is the difference?
2. When is that considered useful or preferable approach?
3. Since everything in Python is an object, **what** or **where** is the object in the last line?

```
class City:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def show_city_name(self):
        print(self.name)

my_city = City("Tokyo")
my_city.show_city_name()

City("Tokyo").show_city_name()
```

Comment: The last line is called with an instance, it's just you don't assign the instance to a variable.

Comment: Executing this code could be useful to see what is actually going on, especially the myriad of objects that are created temporarily.

Comment: `my_city` is not an instance/object - it is a name referring to an object. The expression `City("Tokyo")` creates an object, regardless whether it is then assigned, used, or thrown away.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi So just to confirm, the object is created and thrown away as soon as the method call is done. I understand that (technically) it might not be garbage collected immediately, but conceptually its purpose in this code run is over. And yes, I confused the name with the actual object, but the difference is clear now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `City("Tokyo").show_city_name()` statement results in creation of temporary instance of type `<class '__main__.City'>` on which the `show_city_name()` method is called.

So, the instance is still created, thought it does not bind with any reference to it. We can say that object in in the `City("Tokyo")` expression. Take a look at this:

```
>>> type(City('Foo'))
<class '__main__.City'> # Means it is an instance of the City class
```

Almost the same type of approach (*seemingly invoking a method directly on a class*) can be seen when you have `static` class methods or `@classmethod` decorator. For example:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    # other definitions

    @classmethod
    def unit_circle(cls):
        return cls(1)

unit_c = Circle.unit_circle()

print(unit_c.radius)
# Prints 1
```

This is more correct way and more probable way of doing the same thing in real world code.